# Nested iText table does not show borders

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText 2.1.7 with spring and I am trying to create a PDF document.
I am using a nested table in order to achive something like:

```
      text1                                       text2
 ------------------------------------         ----------------------------
|  text1               text4        |        | text1                      |
|  text2               text5        |        | text2                      |
|  text3                            |        |                            |
|                                   |        |                            |
-------------------------------------        ------------------------------
```

In order to do this i am using 2 nested tables inside a big table, the big table contains the whole segment and the nested tables are what are depicted above.

my code:

```
        Table miniTable1 = new Table(2);
        Table miniTable2 = new Table(1);

        miniTable1.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
        miniTable1.setBackgroundColor(new Color(0, 255, 0));
        miniTable1.setBorderWidth(5);
        miniTable2.setBorderWidth(5);

        //add text here as cells in the mini tables

        Cell cell1 = new Cell(miniTable1);

        Cell cell2 = new Cell(miniTable2);
        cell2.setHorizontalAlignment("center");

        cell1.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(cell1);
        cell2.setColspan(1);
        table.addCell(cell2);
```

The problem is that the borders of the mini tables are not shown.

Answer (score 0):

put the border on the cell, example cell2.setBorderWidth(5f);